# Can functions have output values that aren't mapped?

Tags: functions

I'm working with injective functions and I'm trying to prove that the cardinality of the domain of a function is equal to the codomain of the same function.

Each input value is mapped to a different output value, so it would be true unless there can be output values that aren't mapped?

**Basically my question is, can there be output values that aren't mapped to input values?**

Edit: the function I am trying to figure this out for is stated as being just $f: X \to Y$. I then have to prove the theorem that the domain of function f is equal to the codomain of function f.

Comment: Of course, unless your mapping is onto (surjective)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2$. Clearly $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so since $x^2$ cannot be less than $0$, not all of $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to in the output.

However, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is defined by $f(x) = x^2$, then $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Makes sense thanks. But isn't $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ the same as $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ in this case?

Comment: @bateman - No, as $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \neq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ since $\mathbb{N}$ only takes into account integer values $\geq 0$.

Comment: Surely this isn't injective? -4 and 4 both have a result value of 16?

Comment: @bateman - Yes, of course it's not injective. But it is surjective if you let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: I was asking about injective functions? If I wanted it to be injective I could use N and N right?

Comment: @bateman - Yes, you could use $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Or you could use $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of the domain and the range of an injective function $f$ are always equal, since the range is defined to be the set of points that have preimages under $f$ - and since these preimages are unique, this means that $f$ has an injective inverse and is hence a bijection.

However, the cardinality of a domain and codomain may be different. For instance
$$f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$f(x)=x$$
has the codomain of a larger cardinality than the domain despite $f$ being injective - however, the range of $f$ (which is $\mathbb N$) does have the same cardinality as the domain, but is only a small subset of the codomain.

Comment: I'm confused. You say the cardinality is always equal to begin with and then say at the end they can be different? Sorry I'm new to all this so I'm finding it confusing.

Comment: At the beginning I say the cardinality of the **range** is equal. At the end I say the cardinality of the **codomain** may not be equal. The distinction here is that the range and codomain may be distinct.

Comment: thanks I thought the codomain and range were the same thing.

@Meelo the function I am trying to figure this out for is stated as being just $f: X \to Y$. I then have to prove the theorem that the domain of function f is equal to the codomain of function f or prove it is false

Comment: Giving a counterexample, like the $f$ I wrote, would certainly prove it is false.

Comment: thanks! Last question I promise. Would it still work with $$f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Z$$

Comment: Well, using $f(x)=x$ would not establish that $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ are of the same cardinality. However, it doesn't *prove* that that $\mathbb Z$ is strictly larger - indeed $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ are the same cardinality. Consider also $f(x)=2x$ with $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is not surjective, but still is a map between two sets of equal cardinality.